# Zeeman effect in hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, atomic-physics, hydrogen

Was the [Zeeman effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect) observed for hydrogen atoms **experimentally**? Is there any reference?

Answer (score 3):

Pieter Zeeman has found this effect [purely experimentally](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Hendrik_Lorentz), by burning sodium compound between electromagnets. Further if you would search online, you would find references for Zeeman effect in [hydrogen plasma](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230943553_Observation_of_Zeeman_splitting_of_spectral_lines_from_the_JET_plasma) has been observed too. Finally Zeeman effect is pretty much basic tool for finding out the strength of magnetic field in stars.

Comment: Zeeman effect in hydrogen plasma is the same as the effect in hydrogen atoms? Just to make sure that this precisely answers my question.

Comment: Good question. This [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231045480_Observation_of_ion-cyclotron-frequency_mode_conversion_plasma_rotation_on_HT-7) says that Tokamak plasma has 15% of Hydrogen concentration. Another interesting fact is that Sun photosphere which is a plasma too, is only ionized to about 3% degree, which means that most Hydrogen is in atomic form (not proton only). But strongest argument is that mentioned paper measures Zeeman effect on specific Balmer series line of Hydrogen electron energetic jump $E_{3 \to 2}$. So answer is yes, it's Hydrogen atom spectral split.